# How to style a yaml file?

Tags: styles, yaml

I have a yaml file from which pdf files are created in my system- I don´t really know the first thing about yaml, but have hacked the file enough to get what I want.

Now I need to write bold text inside a line of normal text, but yaml writes normal html tags as text...so hence my question...How could I write bold text inside a line of normal text?

I have read about css styling but I haven´t got this far yet.

thanks for any tips,

Rob